# Mathematical equation to generate ECG signal

Tags: matlab, ecg

I want to generate an ECG signal with PQRS signatures by coding. The signal generated must be repeating in nature. Although I have come across various toolboxes that generate ECG signals, I want to generate them using mathematical equations. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean with "using mathematical equations"? In the end, you'll always construct some kind of function with coefficients modeled after recording (or another model of a heart), so that the formula for the $n$th sample value $s_n = r_{n\mod N}$, where $r$ is some recording, and $N$ is the length after which the signal should repeat, is as valid as any other. But: it's just *playback*. So, please actually describe what you mean with "formula", **and** what you need that formula to do! Otherwise, this remains unclear. It would help if you stated which "various toolboxes" you looked at,

Comment: and what math they used, and why you couldn't use that.

Comment: Thank you Marcus for the cooments. I have gone through many toolboxes. Now, the designed model is working fine.